# Powershell ISE $profile is null

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

Question WRT Powershell ISE on Windows 10 pro.   I recently noticed that when I start powershell ISE, I get an error:
"The term 'set-variable' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet......."

However, if I type set-variable once the powershell prompt shows up, it gives me the usual "Supply values for the following parameters:".....

I have also noticed that modules don't seem to 'autoload' anymore.   I am manually having to do an import-module these data for things that use to work fine.

So figuring something is fouled up with my profile, I went to edit my profile only to notice $profile doesn't have a value in ISE.  So I am wondering if that error I am seeing when ISE starts is it failing to set the value of $profile initially.  (Is there any way to trace this?)

I am not sure of any way to 'repair' powershell ISE and am somewhat stuck as to why it can't find set-variable on start up, which is the reason (I think) that $profile is blank

Version info (it seems to set this properly):

C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSVersionTable
Name                           Value

---

PSVersion                      5.1.19041.1
PSEdition                      Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.19041.1
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1

PSHome value:
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $PSHOME
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

$env:PSModulePath value:
C:\WINDOWS\system32> $env:PSModulePath
C:\Users\craig\OneDrive - Red Dog Systems\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

-- All paths in the above exist.

I am hoping someone out there might have some suggestions on how to sort out what is going on?

Thanks in advance..

cmb..

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple profiles for PowerShell despending on what you have installed.

```
Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
Microsoft.PowerShellISE_profile.ps1
Microsoft.VSCode_profile.ps1
```

As well as several locations for them:

> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7
>
> Description                    Path All Users, All Hosts
> $PSHOME\Profile.ps1 All Users, Current Host
> $PSHOME\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1 Current User, All Hosts
> $Home[My ]Documents\PowerShell\Profile.ps1 Current user, Current
> Host   $Home[My ]Documents\PowerShell\
> Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1

For PowerShell they are not created by default, for say VSCode it is once you, you have to create them. You have to be in the instance you want to create them.

Start powershell.exe or powershell_ise and do this...

```
New-item –type file –force $profile
```

Comment: I have verified that the various profile .ps1 files exist.   The issue is that $profile has no value pointing to them.    I tried initiallizing the profile using if (!(Test-Path -Path $PROFILE ))
{ New-Item -Type File -Path $PROFILE -Force }.   However, $profile has no value and as such when the new item command is run, I get the error: New-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

Comment: You can just copy one from somewhere and rename it and put it in your path. Profiles are empty by default. Just add what you need.

Comment: So that seems to work.  I copied my ISE profile to one other folder and it seems to read the profile properly.  But that doesn't explain why the $profile variable has no value to begin with..

Comment: So, you are saying when you type $profile in the consolehost or the ISE or VSCode, that you are not getting a line that says something like this.... 
  [...\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1]   ? If the file was never created then that would not return. I don't have any machines in that state so no way to revalidate, without spnining one up. Yet, you say, you ran the command and the $profiel is still not populating. That is very strange!

Comment: Corrent.  In ISE, $profile is not defined in any way, shape or form.  If I open a powershell console (non-ise) or powershell core, $profile is defined properly and will return the path where all my profile .ps1 files are located.